# Sass flexbox - layout

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to create RWD layout with header, footer, left and right navbar and main content, however still something is incorrect. I would like to have scrollable main content and footer but main content is still overlapped by footer.
Any hint would be appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/camel99/Lqhary5g/5/

//html

```
<div id="main">
  <header id="header">
    header
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngIf="leftSidebarEnabled">
      <div class="sidebar-left sidebar">
        "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
        accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="rightSidebarEnabled">
      <div class="sidebar-right sidebar">
        voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum
        quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
        eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
        voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam
        corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?
        Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse
        quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
        voluptas nulla pariatur?
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div class="main" [ngClass]="getCssClassesForMainMenu">
      dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
      aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui
      ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem
      ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non
      aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
      exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
      commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
      voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" "Sed ut perspiciatis unde
      omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
      totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
      architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
      quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
      magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro
      quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
      magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
      exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
      commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
      voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" "Sed ut perspiciatis unde
      omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
      totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
      architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
      quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
      magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro
      quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
      velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
      magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
      exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
      commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
      voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" "Sed ut perspiciatis unde
      omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
    doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
  </footer>
</div>
```

//css

```
$headerFooterColor: #4b4276;
$headerFooterHeight: 50px;
$sidebarWidth: 15%;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: $headerFooterHeight;
  background-color: $headerFooterColor;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: $headerFooterHeight;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin-top: $headerFooterHeight;
  .sidebar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: $sidebarWidth;
    background-color: #b9bcc9;
    position: fixed;
    height: calc(100% - (2 * #{$headerFooterHeight}));
    height: calc(100% - (2 * #{$headerFooterHeight}));
    height: calc(100% - (2 * #{$headerFooterHeight}));
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
  }
  .sidebar-left {
    left: 0;
    order: -1;
  }

  .main {
    background-color: rgba(160, 194, 227, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 70%;
    height: calc(100% - (2 * #{$headerFooterHeight}));
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    &.fullWidth {
      width: 100%;
    }
    &.leftSidebarEnabled {
      margin-left: 15%;
      width: 85%;
    }
    &.rightSidebarEnabled {
      margin-right: 15%;
      width: 85%;
    }
  }

  .sidebar-right {
    right: 0;
    order: 1;
  }
}

#footer {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: $headerFooterHeight;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $headerFooterColor;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: try adding padding-bottom to the wrapper

Comment: nope it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Place the `footer` inside `.main` and then in your CSS file changed `position: fixed` inside `footer` to `relative`. Change sidebar height to `height: 100vh`